# First paid invoice for a Contact using Xero API

Tags: xero-api

we are looking to pull those Contacts in Xero which have paid their first ever Invoice within a defined timeframe.

Is there any simple solution to achieving this with the Xero API?

Thanks

Comment: Was using the API (pyxero) and was struggling with the best approach but now I've got it going.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about what you're after - this is achieveable with a couple of requests:

Retrieve all contacts for the organisation:

`GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts`

For each contact, retrieve all invoices:

`GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices?ContactIDs={ContactID}&where=Type%3d%3d%22ACCREC%22`

Get the first invoice for each contact:

`var firstInvoicesForContacts = invoices.GroupBy(i => i.Contact.ContactID, (key, g) => g.OrderBy(i => i.Date).First());`

Out of those, get the ones that have been paid within 5 days of their original date.

`var result = firstInvoicesForContacts.Where(i => i.FullyPaidOnDate.HasValue && i.FullyPaidOnDate.Value < i.Date.Value.AddDays(5));`

Comment: Thanks! I used this to get a solution going